# One step ahead forecasting - VAR

Tags: forecasting, vector-autoregression

Hi I am exploring VAR functions from vars packages

Ive a model fit using following command

```
model_fit <- VAR(diff_raw_prices, p = 5, type = "none")
```

Now i want to perform one step ahead forecasts i.e updating the model with new test data point every time a new value comes in.

I did same in arima by using the model parameter functionality but that is not available for VAR as far as i can see. Do i have to go ahead & re-estimate the model itself?

Comment: Implement it in a rolling window fashion with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy, thx for replying back. 

I need to use the same model i.e not refit & re-estimate the coefficients. 

Following is what i did with arima : 

predicted <- slide_dbl(THE_PRICE_SERIES,  ~ {
      model_new <- stats::arima(.x,order = c(p,d,q),fixed = model_fit$coef,method="ML",include.mean = FALSE)
      return(as.numeric(stats::predict(model_new, n.ahead = 1)$pred))
    }, .before = Inf)

if you notice above, arima function allowed the functionality to give previously trained model object along with the new data received, is something similar possible in VAR

Comment: Im sorry if the comment isn't very clear i'm new to this page, please let me know if i need to expand on my answer 
@RichardHardy

Comment: OK, I got what you mean, but I do not know if there is a function that does that. A little bit of manual coding would help.